# How to clear data from tables with foreign key contraints in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

**I need to delete all the data from some tables**. `DELETE FROM TableTwo`, `DELETE FROM TableOne` etc works (it doesn't reseed but I can learn to live with that).

**I would like to do this by truncating the tables** (because it's faster and I'm certain that when I'm done emptying these tables the data integrity will fine), however TableOne is a dependency of TableTwo, so a naive approach would give me errors "cannot truncate... FOREIGN KEY constraint".

I looked in the constraints folder and tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableOne] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__Blahblah__38EE7070]
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE [TableOne]
GO
ALTER TABLE [TableOne] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Something]
GO
```

However it gives the same error. Also 38EE7070 is unknown to me unless I manually check so I would have run into problems actually using this code anyway.

I wonder if I'm leaving other unknown constraints untouched with, but, confusingly enough, when I try to check `EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableOne'` it shows empty results.

Given the limitations of both sql server and azure a lot of the solutions in other questions don't seem to be workable. Does anyone know how I could proceed? Ie how do I drop and recreate these keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nathan,

There are a couple of things I should point out...

1) The example code you posted is dropping and creating a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT (i.e. something that sets the default value for a column if you do not specify a value during an insert). A default constraint has no affect on the ability to truncate a table (as you rightly point out, a table that has Foreign Key constraints cannot be truncated).

2) I think sp_fkeys was for SQL 2000 and therefore may not work anymore in later versions of SQL Server (even though it still exists).

Below I have attached a script I use to identify all Foreign Key constraints on a table, and generate Create, Drop and Check statements. Although I haven't ever used it on SQL Azure, I have used it many times in a Production enivronment for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Ash

```
CREATE FUNCTION [utils].[uf_ForeignKeyScripts]
(
@PrimaryKeyTable varchar(128), @PrimaryKeyTableSchema varchar(32)
)
RETURNS @Scripts TABLE 
    (
    ForeignKeyName          varchar(128)
,   IfExistsStatement       varchar(1000)
,   DropStatement           varchar(1000)
,   IfNotExistsStatement    varchar(1000)
,   CreateStatement         varchar(1000)
,   CheckStatement          varchar(1000)
,   NoCheckStatement        varchar(1000)
    )
    AS

/*
This function returns statements used to create, drop, and check all Foreign Key constraints that reference a given table.
These statements can be then added to T-SQL scripts.

Example usage (ensure selection of the Results to Text option in SSMS) :

1) To create statements to check all foreign keys

SELECT
    IfExistsStatement + CHAR(13) +
    CHAR(9) + CheckStatement + CHAR(13)
FROM
    utils.uf_ForeignKeyScripts('t_Dim_Date','dbo')      
    ;

This will return a formatted statement to check the existence of a foreign key and if it exists, check that data does not violate the key.

*/

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        @Scripts
        (
        ForeignKeyName
    ,   IfExistsStatement
    ,   DropStatement
    ,   IfNotExistsStatement
    ,   CreateStatement
    ,   CheckStatement
    ,   NoCheckStatement
        )
    SELECT
        FK.name AS ForeignKeyName
    ,   'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + FK.name + ''') ' + 
        'AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '''))'
        AS IfExistsStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' + 
        'DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + CHAR(13) + ';' 
        AS DropStatement
    ,   'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + FK.name + ''') ' + 
        'AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '''))'
        AS IfNotExistsStatement 
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + ' ' + 
        'FOREIGN KEY (' + C.FKColumns + ') ' + 
        'REFERENCES ' + ST.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) + ' ' + 
        '(' + C.FKColumns + ')' + CHAR(13) + ';' 
        AS CreateStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + CHAR(13) + ';'
        AS CheckStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name +   CHAR(13) + ';'
        AS NoCheckStatement
    FROM
        sys.foreign_keys AS FK
    INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS SFK -- schema of foreign key table
    ON
        FK.schema_id = SFK.schema_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.tables AS T -- primary key table
    ON
        FK.referenced_object_id = T.object_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS ST -- schema of primary key table
    ON
        T.schema_id = ST.schema_id
    CROSS APPLY
        (
        /* Get all columns to handle composite keys */
        SELECT 
            SFKC.constraint_object_id
        ,   utils.uf_ConcatanateStringWithDelimiter(COL_NAME(SFKC.referenced_object_id, SFKC.referenced_column_id),', ') AS FKColumns
        FROM
            sys.foreign_key_columns AS SFKC
        WHERE
            SFKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
        GROUP BY
            SFKC.constraint_object_id
        )
        AS C
    WHERE
        OBJECT_NAME(T.object_id) = @PrimaryKeyTable
    AND ST.name = @PrimaryKeyTableSchema
    ;
    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to drop the foreign key, truncate the table, and then re-create the foreign key. For an in-house solution, you would probably take this approach in order to account for the transaction log’s size and performance. In SQL Azure, however, you’re not concerned with the transaction logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my original work (I would like to give credit to the author but don't remember from where I snagged it) but I am posting it because it has found FK constraints on tables for me in SQL 2012 as well as Azure SQL Database:

SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableNameHere' order by TableName